# Haskell how to add a character at the start of a string that has passed by recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hi I'm struggling with this and hope someone can help.

I'm trying to add a character at the start of a string that has already been through recursion.

So to explain, the function takes in a string and outputs a string. The recursion code checks for two characters and replaces them with other chars.

So far so good.

At the end before outputting the string I need to add a character at the start of the string.

E.g.the function needs to replace a space with _ and "d" with "g" And put a "/" at the start. So:

Hello world = /Hello_worlg

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function named `translate`, for example with recursion that transforms `"Hello world"` to `"Hello_worlg"`, then you can use the list "cons" constructor to put a `Char` in front, so:

```
function :: String -> String
function s = '/' : trans s
```

or shorter:

```
function :: String -> String
function = ('/':) . trans
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it within the same function i.e. trans?

Comment: @Nunya: you can work with an "inline" helper function through a `where` clause.

Comment: I know what you're shooting for, but your "shorter" version isn't actually shorter!

Comment: @DanielWagner: now it is :)

Comment: Re inline when
I cannot get the start of the string. No matter what I try. Any help would be good